# What is the $x^8$ term in $(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}})^5(2x - \frac{1}{x^2})^7$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

What is the $x^8$ term in $$(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}})^5(2x - \frac{1}{x^2})^7$$?

I know how to expand $(a+b)^n$ via Newtons binome, but I can't find an elegant way of determining the $x^8$ term without expanding everything.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Think about it this way. To get an integer power of $x$, you need a power of either zero or three in the first expression. That is one of:
$$x^5 \text{  or  }\ {5\choose 2} x^2 \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}^3} = 10 x$$

Answer (score 2):

another hint...write the second term as $$\frac{1}{x^{14}}(2x^3-1)^7$$

Comment: Do this for *both* factors, the first one is $x^{-5/3} (x^{4/3} - 1)^5$